# How to load arbitrary languages from Spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

So I have this function:

```py
import spacy

def foo(lang):
   if lang == "en":
       model = spacy.lang.en.English()
   elif:
```

There are a [ton](https://spacy.io/usage/models#languages) of languages in Spacy and I need to be able to handle them all (with no hardcoding).

Reading their code, they have submodules like `en` and in teh variable `__all__` there is `"English"` but I could not figure out how could I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a `Language` (this does not include any statistical models):

```
nlp = spacy.util.get_lang_class("en")
```